# Integrating a plugin in netbox

Tags: python, django, netbox

I am creating a plugin in netbox. I have run the setup.py file below as prescribed by the documentation

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='netbox_ipdevcir_plugin',
    version='0.1',
    description='A plugin to add many2many models for IP Address, Device and Circuits',
    url='https://gitlab.openaccess.com',
    author='Author',
    license='Apache 2.0',
    install_requires=[],
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

and have gotten the following:

```
root@username:/opt/netbox/netbox/netbox_ipdevcir_plugin# python3 setup.py develop
running develop
running egg_info
writing netbox_ipdevcir_plugin.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to netbox_ipdevcir_plugin.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to netbox_ipdevcir_plugin.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'netbox_ipdevcir_plugin.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'netbox_ipdevcir_plugin.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
Creating /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/netbox-ipdevcir-plugin.egg-link (link to .)
netbox-ipdevcir-plugin 0.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /opt/netbox/netbox/netbox_ipdevcir_plugin
Processing dependencies for netbox-ipdevcir-plugin==0.1
Finished processing dependencies for netbox-ipdevcir-plugin==0.1
root@username:/opt/netbox/netbox/netbox_ipdevcir_plugin#
```

I have then created models which i want now need to sync through the command
./manage.py makemigrations netbox_ipdevcir_plugin

and i am getting

```
(venv) root@username:/opt/netbox/netbox# ./manage.py makemigrations netbox_ipdevcir_plugin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/netbox/netbox/netbox/settings.py", line 613, in <module>
    plugin_config = plugin.config
AttributeError: module 'netbox_ipdevcir_plugin' has no attribute 'config'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/templates.py", line 22, in check_setting_app_dirs_loaders
    for conf in settings.TEMPLATES
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/netbox/netbox/netbox/settings.py", line 616, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Plugin netbox_ipdevcir_plugin does not provide a 'config' variable. This should be defined in the plugin's __init__.py file and point to the PluginConfig subclass.
(venv) root@username:/opt/netbox/ne
```

tbox#

[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwP4I.png)

And the **init**.py is like so

```
    from` extras.plugins import PluginConfig

    class IPDevCirConfig(PluginConfig):
        name = 'netbox_ipdevcir_plugin'
        verbose_name = 'Netbox IPaddres Device Circuit'
        description = 'A plugin for modifying IP Ciurcuit and devices '
        version = '0.1'
        author = Author'
        author_email = 'author.email'
        base_url = 'netbox-ipdevcir'
        required_settings = []
        default_settings = {
            'loud': False
        }
    
    config = IPDevCirConfig
```

Questions

1)What could be the source of this error

2)when developing a plugin the docs do not clearly mention the environment in which the plugin folder is placed. where exactly do you place the plugin folder.
Thank you..

Comment: Focus on one question.

Comment: they are linked because maybe the environment could be the reason

Answer (score 0):

the error was as a result of the programming enviroment. when developing a plugin you have to make sure you are using the virtual enviroment of netbox installation  that you are running or testing with. so for an installation on https://netbox.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ there is a venv folder inside /opt/netbox then source/bin/activate would start a virtual enviroment.